# Use UIAccelerometer to move CCSprite – cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to be able to move a CCSprite using the UIAccelerometer. It should only be moved up and down. The code I use is this:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
valueX = acceleration.y * 45.0;

int newPos = (int)(valueX + _rocket.position.x); 

CGPoint newCenter = ccp(100, newPos);
_rocket.position = newCenter;
}
```

_rocket is the sprite.

When I run it on my iphone it's just vibrating on the same place, and I'm not able to move it to the top or the bottom. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  `int newPos = (int)(valueX + _rocket.position.y);`
   instead `int newPos = (int)(valueX + _rocket.position.x);`

according to your code position.x is always 100. 
That's why `int newPos = (int)(valueX + _rocket.position.x);` not working.

Comment: it works now, thanks. But it moves when I'm tilting the iphone forward and backward, if I want it to move when I tilt it left and right (in portrait mode) How do I do then?

Comment: I'm not with mac right now to test it, but I think you should try the same, but for position.x instead of position.y